# conditional display in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to render text in a text component that is conditional.
if, `this.state.input` is an empty string,
then it should display `this.props.value`.
otherwise, it should display `this.state.input`
is there a way to do that?

```
<text>{
code??
}</text>
```

Comment: [React Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
{
  ( this.state.input === '' )  // ternary operator for checking condition
  ?
  this.props.value  // if condition satisfy
  :
  this.state.input  // if condition doesn't satisfy
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way would be

```
<Text>{this.props.input || this.props.value}</Text>
```

Which means if `this.props.input` is not a falsy value(including an empty string), it will render that, otherwise, it will render `this.props.value`.